# Macports Warning: No port llvm-3.0 found in the index; can't rebuild

Tags: macports

I'm running MacOS/X Sierra 10.12.6 and Macports 2.5.3.
When I do

sudo port install gcc47

I get

Warning: No port llvm-3.0 found in the index; can't rebuild

--->  Broken files found, but all associated ports are not in the index and so cannot be rebuilt.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens when MacPorts finds broken files (e.g. missing files, missing linking dependencies in files installed by a port) after an installation. It will then continue to determine which ports it would have to rebuild to fix the problem.

In your case, a file in the `llvm-3.0` port is broken. This port was removed [almost three years ago](https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/eb784367bb40abde46188cb26da4acc6733c58b3) because it is obsolete. You should find out why it is still needed on your system:

```
$> port installed rdependentof:llvm-3.0 and requested
$> port dependents llvm-3.0
```

and see if the ports listed by those two commands can either be removed completely, or offer variants to select LLVM versions and can be upgraded to use newer LLVM variants.

Comment: I am (still) on OS 10.11.6 and had a similar warning: "Warning: No port llvm-3.8 found in the index; can't rebuild" so I found this post. I have a lot of dependent ports, so in the end I did a  "ln -s libffi.8.dylib libffi.6.dylib" in "/opt/local/lib" because that libffi.6.dylib was missing. Now no more warnings.

Comment: That's precisely what you should not be doing. The reason the filename changed from libffi.6.dylib to libffi.8.dylib was because the interface of the library changed and the developers of libffi wanted you to re-compile all software against the new version. That symlink may now mean that your programs will randomly crash, or potentially behave incorrectly.

Comment: What could I do better? I didn't find libffi.6.dylib in my system and else where :(

Comment: Your copy of llvm-3.8 needs to re-compiled against the newer version of libffi. I'm assuming that would probably work without problems, but llvm-3.8 is outdated and no longer supported by MacPorts. You should switch to a newer version of llvm, which is what my original answer suggested.

Comment: OK, I deleted my symlink and again I have that "Found 1 broken file, matching files to ports" and "Warning: No port llvm-3.8 found in the index; can't rebuild", so I did a "port dependents llvm-3.8" but now I get "llvm-3.8 has no dependents." and "port installed rdependentof:llvm-3.8 and requested" gives me also "None of the specified ports are installed." Could that be because I did previously a "port uninstall inactive"? Or had I destroyed my port installation with that symlink? Strangely all ports (at least what I noticed) were working with my symlink.

Comment: At the moment I have installed ports: https://pastebin.com/vBCTHMDi

Comment: My problems vanished when I switched to OS 10.15. I used a hack to install it on my old Mid 2009 MacBook pro. brew doesn't complain now anymore that the OS isn't supported anymore :)